# rearranging columns in a csv as new lines

Tags: bash

I have the following csv:

```
1,host1,group1,group2
2,host2,group3,group4
3,host3,group5
4,host4,group6,group7,group8
```

I want to achieve the following:

```
1,host1,group1
1,host1,group2
2,host2,group3
2,host2,group4
3,host3,group5
4,host4,group6
4,host4,group7
4,host4,group8
```

How do I do this using linux command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ awk -F , -v OFS=, '{for(i=3;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$2,$i}' data 
1,host1,group1
1,host1,group2
2,host2,group3
2,host2,group4
3,host3,group5
4,host4,group6
4,host4,group7
4,host4,group8
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","}
     {nf=NF;count=3;
     while(nf-2>0){
     printf "%s,%s,%s\n",$1,$2,$count;
     count++;nf--
     }
     }' your_file
```

also would give you the desired result.

```
1,host1,group1
1,host1,group2
2,host2,group3
2,host2,group4
3,host3,group5
4,host4,group6
4,host4,group7
4,host4,group8
```